# Azure DocumentDB partial search against multiple fields

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to query documents using a partial search for serial numbers.  The documents have a structure like this:

```
   {
      "id": "AAAAA",
      "serialNumber": "AAA12345",
      "type1Component":
        {
          "componentId": "component1",
          "serialNumber": "BBBCOMPSN1"
        },
      "type2Component": 
        {
          "componentId": "component2",
          "serialNumber": "CCCCOMPSN2"
        },
      "subComponents": [
        "ZZZCOMP9",
        "YYYCOMP8",
        "XXXCOMP7",
        "ZZZCOMP6"
      ]
    }
```

The query should return documents where any top level or component serialnumber contains a partial match to the input.  For example, the above document should return if the search criteria is any one of the following:  AAA, BBB, CCC, XXX, YYY, ZZZ

Im not sure how to do this.  This is my best attempt so far:

```
    SELECT VALUE root FROM root 
 join comp1 in root.type1Component
 join comp2 in root.type2Component
 join sub in root.subComponents
 where ( contains(upper(root.serialNumber), 'AAA') or
         contains(upper(comp1.serialNumber), 'AAA') or
         contains(upper(comp2.serialNumber), 'AAA') or 
         contains(upper(sub), 'AAA')
       )
```

But this query gets no hits.  Can anyone show me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subComponents array causes a problem with this approach because you'd need to combine an `ARRAY_CONTAINS` with a string `CONTAINS` and there is no way to do that in a query.

Also, the use of `upper()` means it's going to be a full table scan. If you can live with that, you can accomplish this with the following user defined function (UDF):

```
function snSearch (rootSN, sub1, sub2, subArray, s) {

  if (rootSN.toUpperCase().indexOf(s) >= 0) {
    return true;
  };

  if (sub1.serialNumber.toUpperCase().indexOf(s) >= 0) {
    return true;
  };

  if (sub2.serialNumber.toUpperCase().indexOf(s) >= 0) {
    return true;
  };

  var i, len, row;
  for (i = 0, len = subArray.length; i < len; i++) {
    row = subArray[i];
    if (row.toUpperCase().indexOf(s) >= 0) {
      return true;
    };
  };

  return false;
}
```

You call it in a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE 
  udf.snSearch(c.serialNumber, c.type1Component, c.type2Component, c.subComponents, 'ZZZ')
```